# controlar el acceso de los usuarios a un metodo de accion

Tags: asp.net, mvc, controller, users-roles, asp.net-mvc-4

tengo un sistema web que brinda acceso a 3 tipos de usuario (Estudiante, Docente y Admin) en el que quiero restringir el acceso de determinados usuarios a un ActionResult de los controladores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un [`ActionFilterAttribute`](https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/11/15/el-controlador-en-asp-net-mvc-4-iii-action-filters/) sobreescribiendo el metodo `OnActionExecuting` que se ejecuta antes que el metodo Action.

Por ejemplo, a tu clase `Usuario`(o como la llames) agregala una propiedad `Nivel` que tendra el valor de un `enum` llamado `Nivel`:

```
public class Usuario
{
  public string Nombre { get; set;}
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public Nivel Nivel { get; set; }
}

public enum Nivel{
  Estudiante,
  Docente,
  Administrador
}
```

Cuando el usuario inice sesion, guardar la informacion del usuario en el objeto Session. Tienes que asegurarte de asignar la propiedad `Nivel` ya que sera la importante en este caso:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string usuario, string contrasena)
{
    Usuario usuario = ValidarUsuario(usuario, contrasena);
    if(usuario == null)
    {
      ViewBag.Error = "Usuario o contraseña invalido";
      return View();
    }
    else{
     Session["usuario"] = usuario; // guardamos la informacion del usuario
     return View("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Ahora creas una clase que heredara de `ActionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class RequiereNivelAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public RequiereNivelAttribute(Nivel nivel)
    {
      this.nive = nivel;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)  
    {

       // validamos si la sesion ha sido asignada
       if(context.HttpContext.Session["usuario"] != null)
       {
         Usuario = context.HttpContext.Session["usuario"] as Usuario;

         if(usuario.Nivel != this.nivel)
         {
            // como no es del mismo nivel especificado, lo redireccionamos al index de la app
           context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Home/Index"); 
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Ahora solo tendrias que especificar en el Action, el nivel que el usuario requiere para acceder, sino de lo contrario sera redireccionado al /Home/Index:

```
public class ConfigController : Controller
{
  [RequiereNivel(Nivel.Administrador)]
  public ActionResult InfoMaestros()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [RequiereNivel(Nivel.Docente)]
  public ActionResult InfoPerfil()
  {
    return View();
  }

}
```

Si el usuario no tiene el nivel especificado, entonces no podra acceder al action.

Recuerda que es solo un ejemplo. Ya lo adaptaras a tus necesidades y la forma en como deseas hacerlo.

Comment: muchas gracias pana... si me funciono. pero, como puedo hacer para que me permita a 2 tipos de niveles y para que en vez de redirigir a una vista, muestre un mensaje de error o se mantenga en la misma vista